# How to pass an integer array to queue interface in java

Tags: java, arrays, collections, queue

I am trying to create a queue in java which takes up integer array as arguments:

```
Queue<int[]> q=new LinkedList<>();
q.push(new int[]{0,0});
```

I am getting the error:

```
cannot find symbol
    q.push(new int[]{0,0});
     ^
symbol:   method push(int[])
location: variable q of type Queue<int[]>"
```

How do I pass the array to this queue?

Comment: Notice that `q` is a `Queue`, not a `LinkedList`, because you *declared* it to be a `Queue` even if you then *instantiated* it as a `LinkedList`

Comment: Yes, realized it now!

Answer (score 2):

`push()` isn't a method [declared by the `Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html) interface. Use a different method or declare `q` as a `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 0):

Use queue.offer(new int[]{0,0});

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
Queue<int[]> queue = new LinkedList<>();        
queue.add(new int[]{0,0});
```